# grep for pattern

Tags: grep, filter

I have a file where I want to grep for an md5 hash.
I was able to do that but how can I display the match to stdout?

When I do `grep -e "[0-9a-f]\{32\}" file`

I just get:

`Binary file file matches`.
Is there a way to print the result to stdout?

Comment: is it a binary file or is grep just getting confused by, e.g., unicode characters in the filenames inside `file`?   if it's not really a binary file, try `grep -a ...`.  If it is binary, try `grep -a -o ...` or something like `strings file | grep ...`

Comment: You're expecting `file` to be a text file?

Comment: Seems like your file (which we don't know) has some stuff that confuses GNU `grep`. But `sed -nE 's/.*([0-9a-f]{32}).*/\1/p' file` should do the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Usage.html

> **Why does grep report “Binary file matches”?**
>
> If grep listed all matching “lines” from a binary file, it would probably generate output > that is not useful, and it might even muck up your display. So GNU grep suppresses output > from files that appear to be binary files. To force GNU grep to output lines even from
>   files that appear to be binary, use the -a or **‘--binary-files=text’** option. To eliminate > the “Binary file matches” messages, use the -I or **‘--binary-files=without-match’** option.

Comment: This does output the hash correctly, however it also outputs some more junk afterwards that is not part of the pattern.. Is there a way to prevent this? The command used was: `grep -e "[0-9a-f]\{32\}" file --binary-files=text`

Comment: You can use `grep -o` to output only the match, instead of the whole line:

`grep -e -o --binary-files=text"[0-9a-f]\{32\}" file`